# Compressing image size before sending to the firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase-storage, image-compression

As I said at the title I want to compress my image size before uploading image to the firebase storage.
I tried some codes in stackowerflow posts but when I tried it my image rotates and don't preserve it's default orientation. How can fix this problem?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72187991/edit) your post to include what posts were used/what code was used and possibly screenshots of before and after.

Comment: You should read the orientation information which is meta data in the image file. Then rotate your bitmap accordingly if needed.